# How to center the logo, while having the elements near it?

Tags: html, css, navbar

```css
       .header{
    min-height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear- 
    
    gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),
    url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
      
    }

    nav{
    min-height: 7%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 4%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }
    nav img{
    width: 140px;
    }
    .nav-links{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    }
    .nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .nav-links ul li a{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    }
    .nav-links ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f44336;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 1s;    
    }
    .nav-links ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav .fa{
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="header">
        
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="../images/logo.png"></a>
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">  
                <i class="fa fa-close" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="locations.html">LOCATIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>AVEM SALAM</h1>
            <p>AICI CEVA DESCRIERE<br>YOU KNOW SHORT AND GOOD</p>
            <a href="products.html" class="hero-btn">PRODUSELE NOASTRE</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Also, I need some help related to the size of the navbar, how do I make it smaller in terms of height? I did my best to go with "min-height: 7%;" but it is not enough...
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
[![It needs to look smh like this][2]][2]

[![So this how the navbar currently looks][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVWJg.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNswb.png

Comment: You're using a very outdated approach.

Avoid using % - unless you can afford lack of precision or the element should in fact scale with the viewport size.

If you use % for nav height, it'll be huge on vertical screens.

Lastly, try rephrasing your question - I don't know what you're asking about, so I could only give you tips.

Comment: Then, without using %, how can I make it smaller?

Comment: `height: 100px;` for example

Comment: Yup, thanks, it looks better with height: 30px; I do not know all the secrets to CSS.

Comment: Can you also help me center the logo while having the elements near it

Comment: like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNswb.png

Comment: Your HTML is wrong, you need to have 2 separate lists and an image in between of them - unless you want to make image part of your list - which I disadvise.

Comment: crap, I do not know how to do that, well it is going to be a long night, thanks mate for the help with the size of the nav

Comment: I've posted you an answer with the correct HTML - but your CSS and HTML are both very messy and outdated. Good effort thought :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNR4v.png thanks mate, also did .nav-links{ text-align: center} and it looks better, goona play with the position later

Comment: I know about the messy part, been coding for ~7 weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM order is wrong, try this HTML

```html
   <section class="header">
        
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">  
                <i class="fa fa-close" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="../images/logo.png"></a>
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">  
                <i class="fa fa-close" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="locations.html">LOCATIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>AVEM SALAM</h1>
            <p>AICI CEVA DESCRIERE<br>YOU KNOW SHORT AND GOOD</p>
            <a href="products.html" class="hero-btn">PRODUSELE NOASTRE</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want elements around your logo and Logo to be centered then your code is totally written wrong.

make parent-div with display property:flex

and then make three child div with class **nav-left** **logo** and **nav-right** and give them width of percentage 33.33 %

include ul li in first div with class nav-left

then add your logo with in second div element so that you can control your image responsiveness

and lastly include ul li in third div with class nav-right

**ABOUT HEIGHT**

remove height from nav and I am assuming you are new to code then you should also do this

```
ul,li {
   padding: 0;
   margin : 0;
```

}

it should be done before you start styling because some html tags have default padding and margins (give this search on Google so you know which tags have this default styling e.g are p tags heading-tags anchor-tags etc,..) you have to remove this and then add your styles. Hope this will help you out :)